# Non-root users Installing packages from a rpm file

Tags: linux, centos, system-administration

I'm a non-root user running centos Linux.....the problem is i have the desired rpm file i don't how to install them into my home directory being a non-root user.Any help would be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: What type of rpm? Containing a binary? Then install after extracting the rpm. Or build from source and give install prefix as your your directory.

Comment: Thanks for cmntng khrm.....how to install the package from an extracted rpm file?? howover i will give a try for building using prefix....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

This nice little script ( unPack_rpm.sh ) will unpack rpm packages to a folder with the package name ...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Purpose: Unpack RPM archives (author: @unSpawn)
# Args: /path/to/archive
# Deps: Bash, GNU utils, RPM
rpmDetails() { for Q in changelog provides requires scripts triggers triggerscripts; do 
 rpm -q -p --${Q} "${f}" 2>&1 | grep -v NOKEY > "${Q}.log"; done; }
rpmUnpack() { f=$(readlink -f "${f}"); file "${f}"|grep -q "RPM.v" && \
 { d=$(basename "${f}" .rpm); d="./${d:=ERROR_$$}"; mkdir -p "${d}" && \
 { cd "${d}" && rpm2cpio "${f}" | cpio -idmv && rpmDetails "${f}"; }; }; }
for f in $@; do rpmUnpack "${f}"; done
exit 0
```

---

Comment: This works succesfully and unpacks an rpm file but how to install that into my home directory after unpacking the rpm file

Comment: ? Which `.rpm` ? ... Lots of different behaving "rpm´s". A library package is usually portable : Libs can go in /home/[name]/lib/. Applications (Tools) : Please specify package.rpm . -

Comment: can glibc's content of lib and include be unpacked and added to the lib and include folders of the home directory

Answer (score 0):

I think this is somewhat a duplicate question, the same as the one [here](https://superuser.com/questions/209808/how-can-i-install-an-rpm-without-being-root). In this thread, it is suggested to extract the rpm (using conversion to cpio) and then use the source files locally.

A link to an in-depth explenation for this is also supplied, you can see it [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html).

Comment: I have already tried them but the technique insisted would be working if only iam working in the same directory where the rpm files have been extracted but i want a global usage in my account...

Comment: Can't you add an alias to the binary file? That way you can call the program from any directory.

Comment: Thanks for writing back.....iam an newbie to linux can you provide a link about doing the thing that u were insisting me...

Comment: If you ever want to know something in bsh you could use 'apropos'. Here is more information on bash aliases: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html